# Formalizing "The distribution of $X$ given $\mathcal{G}$ is equal in law to $Y$"

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space and 
$\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F}$ a sub-sigma algebra. 
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables (with respect to $\mathcal{F}$).

What does the statement: 
"The distribution of $X$ given $\mathcal{G}$ is equal in law to $Y$"
mean formally?

Does it mean that for all non-negative measurable functions 
$f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ we have 
(with $E$ denoting $P$-expectations)

$$E(f(X)| \mathcal{G}) = E(f(Y)| \mathcal{G}) \quad ? $$

Comment: Formally, it doesn't make sense, as far as I can tell.  The conditional distribution of a random variable is not a random variable, and it doesn't make sense to say it is equal in law to another random variable.  Can you say where you read this statement, and perhaps give more context?

Comment: @NateEldredge isn't it just saying $X$ given $\mathscr{G}$ is distributed like $Y$? Or am I misreading this?